# ASP Getting radio checked value

Tags: asp-classic

I'm sure someone will help with this:

Basically I got a form which on submit, it directs it to my contact_form.asp which then sends out an email to a specified address, well I got some Radio buttons on that form, and need to get the checked radio button out of a group of about 3 radio buttons.

i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceDaily" value="Daily">  Daily </input>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceWeekly" value="Weekly">  Weekly</input>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceMonthly" value="Monthly">  Monthly</input>
```

and in my contact_form.asp I am requesting the value like:

```
group1 = Request("group1")
```

Am I doing something wrong? i.e. getting the value incorrectly? The response I'm getting is "Group1", not "Daily" as I want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a test page using the code you supplied and it works fine (see below).

Try a http debugging tool such as [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to investigate the actual parameters and values passed between the two pages.

```
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
<form method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceDaily" value="Daily">  Daily </input> 
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceWeekly" value="Weekly">  Weekly</input> 
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceMonthly" value="Monthly">  Monthly</input> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div> 
<%
Dim group1
group1 = Request("group1") 
Response.Write ("group1='" + group1 + "'")
%>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Haha I don't know how, but it just worked..... I really don't know what I did wrong, maybe just a little typo... :) Thanks! +1